# Change presenting viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue, modalviewcontroller

Heyo,

Right now I've got an app that presents a menu screen that partially covers the original screen, and can be used to navigate to other screens. This is done using a modal segue.

To get to another screen the from the base page the menu is presented, the user selects the next screen in the menu, the menu is dismissed, and THEN the segue to the next screen is preformed.

What I've spent a few weeks trying to figure out, however, is how to dismiss this menu DIRECTLY to a viewcontroller OTHER than the one that's presenting it.

I'm thinking I've got to figure out how to change a presenting view, but I haven't had any luck.

Currently I'm completely at a loss, and any recommendations/fixes would be great!

Comment: i suggest you restructure. Have a root view controller that contains your current ViewController and can present a menu over the top. Selecting a new menu item simply changes the contained UIViewController. There quite a few menu controllers at cocoacontrols.com

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I might resort to that, but I like stemming navigation from the currently presenting page.

Comment: All of the menu systems I have seen use the technique I described. You can change the rootviewcontroller property on the keyWindow of UIApplication though.

Comment: The other advantage of the container approach is that the menu controller keeps a strong reference to all of the other controllers so when you swap around your context for each ViewController is kept

Comment: Paul, you are so right. You've made me realize how ignorant I am. Restructing now. Thanks again. My tree is getting so much cleaner!